# NMaximize with a list of variables

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization

I want to use `NMaximize` to find the maximum value of a function with multiple variables. The problem is I would like to set this up so the number of variables is only decided when the function sees the data. So I have:

```
NMaximize[{F[data,a1,a2],a1>0,a2>0},{a1,a2}]
```

when there are data from two genes.
But would like the function to be

```
NMaximize[{F[data,a1,a2,a3],a1>0,a2>0,a3>0},{a1,a2,a3}]
```

if there are 3 genes...etc Any way to set this?

Answer (score 5):

Does this do what you want?

```
func[syms__Symbol] := NMaximize[{F[data, syms], Thread[{syms} > 0]}, {syms}]

func[q, r, s, t]
```

> ```
> NMaximize[{F[data, q, r, s, t], {q > 0, r > 0, s > 0, t > 0}}, {q, r, s, t}]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've almost got it to work using `pList = Table[Symbol["a"<>ToString[i]],{i,1,n}]` to generate my list of variables, but there's a complication I'm still working on.

Comment: @user6799 Can I help with whatever that complication is?